# remove index.php from getBaseUrl()

Tags: magento2, base-url

I write `echo $block->getBaseUrl()` in my .phtml template, and show output http://localhost/magento2/index.php/. I want to remove `index.php` from that output. How can i do that?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya basically your answer and denish answer is the same :)

Comment: Yes, but I answer you first. NP :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

URL rewrites will remove index.php from url

How to enable URL rewrites?

```
1   Stores > Configuration > Web
2   expand the Search Engine Optimization section
3   set Use Web Server Rewrites to “Yes.”
4   When complete, tap Save Config
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: and then `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: setup:upgrade for a config change? Surely not.

Comment: just need to reindex and clear cache after.

Comment: Stores > Configuration > **General** > Web. 'Web' tab is under 'General' Tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the index.php in the frontend URLs performing the following steps in Magento's admin section:

In **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations**, select **YES**.

Edit the `/rootdir/.htaccess` and uncomment the line:

```
RewriteBase /magento2/
```

In my case the subdirectory Magento is in is called `magento2`, so change it to your subdirectory path if it is different.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.2: Add below line in .htaccess File

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

After that enable URL Rewrites from Admin:

1. Stores>Configuration> Web
2. Expand the Search Engine Optimization section
3. Set Use Web Server Rewrites to “Yes.”
4. When complete, tap Save Config