# Deleting the /index.php from the URL

Tags: magento2

How can I delete the /index.php from the frontend URL's?
Thank you!

Comment: You can refer this link [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141736/remove-index-php-from-getbaseurl](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141736/remove-index-php-from-getbaseurl)

Comment: Sorry, why you cannot delete it .It is entry point  of route of url.

Comment: Check your `.htacess`. Rewrite rule from `.htacess` removed `index.php` from Url.

Comment: the .htaccess solution worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sorry, why you cannot delete it .It is entry point  of route of url for both  frontend and admin section.**

> If delete it then both and admin will not work.

I guess that you want remove index.php from admin.

***That can be done via magento setting***

> - 1.Goto admin> Stores > Configuration > Web
> - 2  Then goto Search Engine Optimization section
> - 3  Set Web Server Rewrites to **Yes**
> - 4  Save Config

**`But make sure Mod rewrite is enabled at Apache or nginx` level**

Comment: simple rewrite, to avoid google index with /index.php